# Obtener únicamente cierta información de un Json y pasarla a un Array

Tags: java, json, array

Supongamos que tengo el siguiente Json

```
{"items":[{"dt":58,"ubicacion":"x","xs":"x"},{"dt":00,"ubicacion":"x","xs":"no"},{"dt":240,"ubicacion":"y","xs":"no"},{"dt":383,"ubicacion":"p","xs":"no"},{"dt":460,"ubicacion":"x","xs":"no"},{"dt":899,"ubicacion":"g","xs":"no"}]}
```

Y que solo quiero los Arrays donde se contiene el valor "x" en "ubicacion", estaba pensando en hacer algo como lo que se ve en el código de abajo, pero no estoy seguro si con ese método la demás información se conserve, la verdad me bloquee así que cualquier información que puedan compartir será bienvenida.

```
private void parseItems(String jsonResposnce) {
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

try {
    JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(jsonResposnce);
    JSONArray jarray = jobj.getJSONArray("items");


    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject jo = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

        String dt = jo.getString("dt");
        String ubicacion = jo.getString("ubicacion");
        String xs = jo.getString("xs");
        HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<>();
        if (ubicacion.equals("x")){
        item.put("dt", dt);
        item.put("ubicacion", ubicacion);
        item.put("xs", xs);
        list.add(item); }

    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}}
```

Comment: JSONObject es de Jackson?

Comment: No, es un Json obtenido de una hoja de Google.

Comment: Cuál es la pregunta? Has probado y no te funciona? Qué es lo que no te funciona?

Comment: @SuperG280 Ya he trabajado con el método que se ve arriba quitando el if para pasar los datos a un ArrayHashMap y funciona, ahora solo me gustaría tomar un valor en especifico pero solo me toma los key donde se encuentran esos valores que busco, me gustarían tomar donde se encuentra “x” en ubicacion, tomar todos los valores (“cp”, “ubicacion” y “xd”) y ponerlos en un HashMap donde “cp” sea Key y los otros sus value.

Answer (score 0):

Quitando la indentación del if, lo veo todo correcto. Ese codigo mete en `list` solo los objetos del json que tienen `ubicacion` x.

Pero tus objetivos parecen contradictorios, solo quieres los que tienen x y no perder información. ¿Tal vez quieres dos listas, una con todos y otra con solo los x?

PD: Jackson es el nombre de una libreria para usar json

Comment: Lo que buscó es hacer un HashMap con los los datos(“dt”, “ubicación”, “ xs”), donde “dt” sea el Key y los otros dos datos sean sus values, pero únicamente de los que tengan un “x” en “ubicación” (no sé si me explico, si no dime). En el método sin el if me vacía todos los datos del JSON.